# How to show build datetime on my react web app using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

tl;dr version - I want to show the date of deployment of the production application on the footer of my application so that the users know exactly when the application was last updated.

I want it to be automatic, but I can't think of a way to capture the current date time during build and then parse it into html (jsx) to show them.

**Update** - Btw, I use CRA and have no plans of ejecting from it! At least not for this.

**Context - Why do I want this?**
I have a production application in React that I don't have unrestricted access to. There were some issues raised on there and I was able to replicate it on my dev and I fixed the issues and deployed it (or I thought I did). But the issue remained on production and after more time debugging, I just asked for a lot of diagnostic information from them to check if there was something wrong with the production API or database etc. But it finally turned out that my deployment to production wasn't successful. I think that if I showed the last deployement date-time somewhere on the app, I could just ask that from the users rather than get into elaborate diagnostic information.

Comment: you can create an env variable calculating to data and time and access the variable in your footer component. process.env.BUILD_DATE_TIME. That way you can show the approx date and time of your build.

Comment: Ok, but how do I update the env variable exactly on build time?

Comment: look your BUILD_DATE_TIME variable will be calculated at compile time precisely when your bundler creates chunks. That's the reason I said approx above. this way your problem will be solved. you will get distinct date and time everytime you give a build to production

Comment: Tried this, but CRA automatically sanitizes all environment variables except for NODE_ENV for security/privacy reasons (link - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

so the BUILD_DATE_TIME variable, if it is normally available on node.js, won't be available on CRA.

Comment: Ahh I missed one point you need to give the env varibable as REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE_TIME . This should work. ANd then access it in your footer component . process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE_TIME. Then it should work

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm a Create React App maintainer!

Starting in Create React App 2 (`react-scripts@^2.0`) you can accomplish this via macros.

First, install `preval.macro`:

```
$ npm install --save preval.macro # if using npm
$ yarn add preval.macro # if using yarn
```

Next, in the file you want to render a build timestamp in, include `preval.macro`:

```
import preval from 'preval.macro'
```

Finally, you can create a constant and use it in your app like so:

```
const dateTimeStamp = preval`module.exports = new Date().toLocaleString();`
```

Here's a full example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import preval from 'preval.macro'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Build Date: {preval`module.exports = new Date().toLocaleString();`}.
          </p>
        </header>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: This is working. I tried to upgrade my app to react-scripts 2. Got it to start compiling after fixing dependency issues. But after that, there's a lot of problems within my application that were never complained about, but are now being complained about. A lot of these errors don't even come with line numbers etc. *sigh* Getting my app to work on react-scripts 2 is going to take more time than I anticipated. But this solution works, I tried it on a new app. Thanks!

Comment: "A lot of these errors don't even come with line numbers etc" That behavior sounds like a bug! Can you please file an issue with more information so we can take a closer look?

Comment: Sorry, I'm held up with some other issues in a production application. Can't get to the react-scripts2.0 migration right now. But when I do, I'll update about unusual errors here. Thanks!

Comment: See some discussion on this solution here - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4960

Comment: I tried this in my app and it works. Can I move the preval line in a (component inside a) package and yet have it evaluated at app build time (not component build time)?

Answer (score 5):

The solution from [joe-haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4397028/joe-haddad) is working well. Here is a drop-in component you can use like `<VersionNumber />`. This will display something like:

[image]

```
import React       from 'react';
import moment      from 'moment';
import packageJson from '../../../package.json';
import preval      from 'preval.macro';

const buildTimestamp = preval`module.exports = new Date().getTime();`;

class Component extends React.Component {
    getDateString = () => {
        const lastUpdateMoment = moment.unix(buildTimestamp / 1000);
        const formattedDate    = lastUpdateMoment.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');

        return formattedDate;
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {packageJson.version}
                {'.'}
                {buildTimestamp}
                {' '}
                {'('}
                {this.getDateString()}
                {')'}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Component.propTypes = {};

Component.defaultProps = {};

export default Component;
```

Comment: Can this be moved in a package that the app has as dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Set a process environment using webpack. You can save the value to a local json file and read from it with an increment during the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

A contribution to [Joe Haddat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035483/1029816); if you want to illustrate the build date by using `preval.macro` in the viewer timezone instead of the environment timezone which builds the app, here is how to do it;

```js
render() {
  const buildDate = preval`module.exports = new Date();`
  return (
     <div>Build Date: {new Date(buildDate).toLocaleString()}</div>
  )
}
```

This will save the build date, but turning it into a locale string will still happen on runtime, on the browser where the viewer timezone is used.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple approach with minimum work needed is to set an environment variable in the build script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build", // This is the line we will edit, it may not be craco build but maybe react build
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Change this line into this

```
"build": "export REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(date) && craco build",
```

notice that `date` is just some command in the terminal use whatever commands or arguments you like

In JSX, in any element just get the build date like this

```
<span>build {process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME || "debug"}</span>
```

Where I set the default value to be "debug".

Answer (score -1):

```
    function getClientEnvironment(publicUrl) {
      const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
        .filter(key => REACT_APP.test(key))
        .reduce(
          (env, key) => {
            env[key] = process.env[key];
            return env;
          },
          {
            // Useful for determining whether we’re running in production mode.
            // Most importantly, it switches React into the correct mode.
            NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
            REACT_APP_DATE_TIME: new Date().toDateString(),
            // Useful for resolving the correct path to static assets in `public`.
            // For example, <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />.
            // This should only be used as an escape hatch. Normally you would put
            // images into the `src` and `import` them in code to get their paths.
            PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl,
          }
        );
      // Stringify all values so we can feed into Webpack DefinePlugin
      const stringified = {
        'process.env': Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
          env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
          return env;
        }, {}),
      };

      return { raw, stringified };
    }

module.exports = getClientEnvironment;
```

The old solution will also work. Please check the code again. As i can see the proper value in my app.

Comment: Tried this, but it just renders it as string  "new Date().toDateString()".

Can't run JS code on a .env file right?

Comment: now i  need to run it and check man. There are many gotchas here :) . Let me try it.

Comment: Can you please give me some context as to what to do with that function? Where do I put it, where do I call it, when?

So far I've only used env variables in .env.development and .env.production files. Is there another way to define env variables in CRA?

Comment: You are using create react app as you have mentioned above. So go to YourProject/config/env.js. There you will find this function already written I have only added one line REACT_APP_DATE_TIME: new Date().toDateString(), to it

Comment: I didn't already have a config/env.js file. I however tried creating a config folder and added a env.js file with the code above, didn't work. I also tried putting the env.js file inside the root directory. Didn't work. Are you using a env dependency like dotenv or something? Because when you create a create-react-app by using `npx create-react-app <app-name>`. It doesn't automatically create config/env.js.

Also can you show me the scripts section in your package.json?

Comment: I am logging an issue regarding this on your behalf. Even I am not sure how to do this in un ejected situation. My app was ejected that's the reason I was able to do it. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5598.